# enable freebase on the Google API's page not working?

Tags: freebase

Can anyone give me an indication as to why, when i try to enable the Freebase API on the Google Cloud Console, it appears to load a loader but nothing happens.

Am I doing something spectacularly stupid or is there a problem here?

Comment: I have the same problem and still can not solve it, I think the service is down for some reason